# PHP Select Box...after selection help needed (yii)

Tags: php, select, menu, yii

I am using a script that runs on the YII framework... 
I have this select box that lets a user view content based on their country. But right now, when a user selects their country, after the selection, it just shows the country name... 
And what I want is, after a user selected their country... it must still show the select box, but have the selected country at the top of the list.
I have tried so many things but I'm still new to this this.

```
<?php if ( $_country == '' ) { ?>
<select onchange="changeCountry(this)" name="country" id="country">
<?php if ( count ($c) != 0 ) { ?>
<?php if ( $_country == NULL ) ?>
<?php foreach ($c as $id => $val) { ?>
<option<?php if ($id == $countryId) {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?php echo mbCoreFunctions::to_seo_ad_name ($val, $id) ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="countryName"><?php echo $countryName; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you answer aside, You dont have to use begin and ending tags with each php line you know. And your question does not give enough information about what you want to accomplish. Can you elaborate it more. The code doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try but following should work

```
<select onchange="changeCountry(this)" name="country" id="country">
    <?php foreach ($c as $id => $val) { ?>
    <option<?php if ($id == $countryId) {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?php echo mbCoreFunctions::to_seo_ad_name ($val, $id) ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanx for the help! Worked great!